# Image hyperlink not working anymore from Office 2013 to Office 365

Tags: microsoft-excel, office365, hyperlink

I have an hyperlink from an image to a tab like this (got from unzipping the excel):

```
<Relationship Id="rId32" Target="%23Paid%20Benefits%20(Pool)!A8" TargetMode="External" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/hyperlink"/>
```

Here's how the link shows on office 2013:

```
file:///C:\Users\myname\download\FileName - Paid Benefits (Pool)!A8
```

However in Office 365 shows as

```
file:///C:\Users\myname\download\%23Paid Benefits (Pool)!A8
```

Why does Office 365 does not read %23 as the Uri Fragment # locating correctly the resource as done in Officse 2013?

This is driving me crazy

Thanks

Davide